# Redirecting stderr into a temp file

Tags: c++, c, unix, stderr, io-redirection

On windows I would use something like this:

```
strcpy (errorFileName, _tempnam (NULL,"pfx"));
freopen (errorFileName, "wt", stderr);
```

But the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tempnam.3.html) for `tempnam` in linux specifically says **not** to use it and to use [`mkstemp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html) instead. Fair enough. But it returns a file descriptor instead. Is there any easy way to use `mkstemp` to redirect `stderr` into the file? And *also* store the file name generated by `mkstemp` for future use in the program if necessary?

```
int fd = mkstemp("pfxXXXXXX");
if (fd != -1)
{
    //get file name here? or is there a better way
    strcpy (errorFileName, nameFromFd);
    freopen (errorFileName, "wt", stderr);
}
```

Comment: Why not let the user decide where he wants to see his output?

Comment: @BaummitAugen They do decide, this is part of a method that executes only if they specify the option. Either way it's not my code. I can't make design decisions like that.

Comment: What I mean is that the user can just  redirect `stderr` from outside the program if he wants to, so there is no need to do this in your code.

Comment: If you really want to do this inside your program, just use a variable: `FILE* output = b?stderr:tmpfile("log")` and write to `output` instead of `stderr`. It will be clearer than modifying global state.

Comment: As you appear to be using C++, please remove the C tag. These are different langauges and a solution is likely specific.

Comment: @Olaf The program is 25 years old and the core of the program is written entirely in C. It was adapted over time to use C++ but is probably 90% completely C. For other people: the solution might be specific. For my question it is not.

Answer (score 3):

You want to look into dup2().

```
   dup2(fd,2);
```

should do the trick:

```
   int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd);

   dup2() makes newfd be the copy of oldfd, closing newfd first if  neces-
   sary, but note the following:

   *  If  oldfd  is  not a valid file descriptor, then the call fails, and
      newfd is not closed.

   *  If oldfd is a valid file descriptor, and newfd has the same value as
      oldfd, then dup2() does nothing, and returns newfd.
```

Source: man dup

Comment: If the documentation you showed is a quote (as the formatting suggests), you should add a source, possibly as a link.

Comment: Make sure this is the first thing you do in your program. Mixing operations on `*FILE` and file descriptors might lead to strange results.

Comment: Source is the man page for dup/dup2/dup3, which is the normal way of looking up C library functions on a unix system. "man dup2" would give you that information.

Answer (score 0):

To Answer your second part of the question, to store the file name generated by mkstemp for future use in the program if necessary,  just use a local variable to store the fileName

```
char nameBuff[32];
memset(nameBuff,0,sizeof(nameBuff));
strncpy(nameBuff,"/tmp/myTmpFile-XXXXXX",21);
mkstemp(nameBuff);
printf("\n Temporary file [%s] created\n", nameBuff);
```